# Get results only when multiple cells are changed VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that fills the date in column 3 when the there is a change in values of a cell `Range("E:J")`. It works fine, but I would also like to display the values of column 4 (col 4 is hidden) in column 11, only when all the cells in the `Range(E:J)` are filled.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("E:J")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Value <> vbNullString Then
        Target.Offset(0, 3 - Target.Column).Value = Date
        Target.Offset(0, 3 - Target.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mmm/yyyy"
    Else
        Target.Offset(0, 3 - Target.Column).ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tc As Long, r As Range, tr As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    tc = Target.Column
    tr = Target.Row
    If Intersect(Target, Range("E:J")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set r = Range(Cells(tr, "E"), Cells(tr, "J"))

     Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Value <> vbNullString Then
            Target.Offset(0, 3 - tc).Value = Date
            Target.Offset(0, 3 - tc).NumberFormat = "dd/mmm/yyyy"
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 3 - tc).ClearContents
        End If

        If wf.CountA(r) = 6 Then
            Cells(tr, 11).Value = Cells(tr, 4).Value
        End If

     Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```